# Using SQLite from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am having problems writing statements, especially when updating.

- I want to update a column with a parameter, but I don't know the special characters to use like `@` or `%d`.

I tried to do:

```
const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"update lugar set frecuencia ='d%'aumentador Where idLugar = '%d'",
  idLugarParametro] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I get a problem with: `frecuencia ='d%'aumentador`

- How can I find a guide or tutorial for using this special characters for creation statements? (Using Objective C specifically.)

Comment: There is no good reason to use the sqlite C api directly.  Use a wrapper: http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/resources/sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Here's the Apple documentation for [NSString stringWithFormat](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:), and [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

I note that it seems you typed `d%`, but probably meant `%d` for the format specifier (you might need an extra space in there too), and that 
you've only supplied one arg (idLugarParametro), but your format string has two specifiers:

```
------------------------------1v------------------------------2v
update lugar set frecuencia ='%d' aumentador Where idLugar = '%d'
```

so you need to supply two values - the new frecuencia value is not there.

Lastly, suggest that you look in to the use of prepared statements once you've got the hang of the basics - see the SQLite docs.